# Proper way to wrap a method in a Promise with bluebird?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Trying to figure out how to piece out some functionality into an api, such that whatever methods that I call are promise-based.

I've used `Q` and `async`, but I'm starting to learn to use bluebird.

Do I need wrap my `join` method within `user_api` within a `new Promise(function()`?

```
// users_api.js
// ---------------------------
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var genSalt = Promise.promisify(bcrypt.genSalt);
var genHash = Promise.promisify(bcrypt.hash);

exports.join = function(req) {
  // Generate a salt, and return a hash based off
  // of the incoming password.
  var hashPassword = function () {
    return genSalt(10).then(function (salt) {
      return genHash(req.body.password, salt);
    });
  };

  return hashPassword().then(function(hash) {
    new User({
      email: req.body.email,
      username: req.body.username,
      created: new Date(),
      confirmed: 0,
      last_login_ip: req.ip,
      created_ip: req.ip,
      last_login: new Date(),
      hash: hash
    }).save().then(function(userModel) {
      console.log('saved', userModel);
       // resolve this promise
    }).catch(function(e) {
      console.log(e);
      // throw an error to the caller (within users_controller)
    });
  });
};


// users_controller.js
// ---------------------------
user_api = require('user_api');

exports.join = function (req) {
  // I want this `join` method to function as a promise so I can chain off of it.

  user_api.join(req).then(function(res) {
    console.log('all done');
  }).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
};
```

Comment: Regardless of which lib you are using, the fundamental requirement for a "method to function as a promise" is that the method returns a promise. How that promise is derived depends on the nature of the method but there are two bases, (i) return a promise obtained as the return value from another function/method call, (ii) create a promise. (In each case, the base promise may be chained such that some resultant promise is actually returned).

Comment: Looking at the code in the question, it would appear that `users_controller.join()` is lacking nothing more than the `return` keyword before `user_api.join(...)...`, in the same way that `user_api.join()` itself has a return statement.

Comment: Indeed you just need a return statement, and get rid of those catch clauses because you are not doing anything useful in them - if you don't have a catch clause anywhere an unhandled error will be logged with stack trace (which gives lots of context if you have enabled long stack traces). Right now you logging the error twice and swallowing it so the application cannot handle it at the right place (ui layer).

Comment: @Esailija see - just the sort of question I've been talking about. I wonder if warning about a promise created in a scope but undefined returned wouldn't be helpful